# Call method for Twilio on Parse Cloud Code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, twilio, voip

We are trying to implement simple P2P VoIP connection between iOS devices. We picked Twilio to handle calls and using Parse to interact with Twilio.

We are successfully generating capability tokens per user and initiate a call. However call is hanging up instantly after successful connection.

Receiver is receiving the call successfully and hearing the trial message.
Initiator is hearing the trial message and also "Application error occurred.".

We are suspecting that there may be something wrong at our call method on Parse Cloud Code.

```
app.get('/call', function(request, response) {
var client = require('twilio')('ACC_ID', 'AUTH_ID');
// Create a TwiML response generator object
var fromName = 'client:' + request.query.from;
var toName = 'client:' + request.query.to;

    client.makeCall({
        to:toName, // Any number Twilio can call
        from: fromName, 
        url: 'http://xxxyyzz.parseapp.com/consult' // A URL that produces an XML document (TwiML) which contains instructions for the call

    }, function(err, responseData) {

        //executed when the call has been initiated.
        console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"

    });

    });
```

We are not sure about what should url parameter supposed to do.

```
app.post('/consult', function(request, response) {

    response.send();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, but there seems to be a problem in your `/call` service (you also don't need any other urls, `/call`' should be enough).

What Twilio expects as a response from `/call` is a TwiML message (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml). Your server here should respond proper TwiML so that Twilio will know what to do.

If you want to connect two clients then `/call` should return the `Dial` TwiML message. The documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) can let you know about the details of the `Dial` message. There are some interesting options such as limiting the phone call to 40 seconds for example.

If you want to dial a client called 'Jenna', then the response from your `/call` service should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Client>Jenna</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Good luck with your application, hope this helps!